# Wrong day count between two date

Tags: c#, datetime, count

```
var datetime1 = DateTime.Now;
var datetime2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
Console.WriteLine((datetime2-datetime1).TotalDays);
```

`datetime1` value is 11:30 PM
`datetime2` value is a date time value plus more 5 hours.

The console output must be 2. But the result is 0.2xxxxxxxxxx.

I thinks above code calculate days count base on hour of two date. Not based on day of two date.

What should I do to make the output is 2?

Comment: The result is correct. 5 hours time difference are approximately 20 % of a full day hence the result 0.2. This is how the property `TotalDays` is defined.

Comment: You want it to be 2 because the time range encompasses at least part of a day on 2 different dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not wrong. The `TotalDays` displays fractional days, and 5 hours (out of 24) is roughly `.2` days.

To display the fact that you're dealing with a span of two separate days, ignore the time portion:

```
Console.WriteLine((datetime2.Date - datetime1.Date).Days + 1);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Your result is `1` in his example, not 2.

Comment: Incorrect. `Days` is always 0 if `TotalDays` is 0.2. The property sits on the 'TimeSpan' type hence it is not aware of the time, only the time span. Run your code please.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst: The answer works correctly. The difference will not be 0.2, it will be 1 (because the `.Date` is throwing away the time portion).